# Issue in writing CBCharacteristic

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I am currently working on an BLE app which scans my company beacons , i need to update the values for CBCharacteristic .

I am not getting any error after my write function , but the change does not reflect on BLE device.

I have scanned  all CBCharacteristics and then traversing to get particular and calling write function

```
for (CBCharacteristic* characteristic in beaconCharacteristics)
{
    if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"FFF5"]]) {
        [characteristic.service.peripheral writeValue:[@"BeaconE" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
    }
}
```

even i get completion delegate method called after writing without an error

```
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
}
```

Am i missing anything ? Is it due to hex value ?

Please guide me

Thank you !

Comment: Once you wrote your new data, on the `peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:` if you try to read it, has the value changed? What does it changes exactly? Its name? If yes, and your try is to check if the device name changed, it may be due to some cache.

Comment: I have CBCharacteristics for name , minor , major , udid , etc .Also value does not change in peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:

Comment: After writing a new value you need to issue a read operation against the characteristic before you will see the new value in CoreBluetooth. If the value isn't actually changing in the device then either your device has a problem or you aren't sending the correct sequence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It could be that the Characteristic is read only.  You can find out by looking at the CBCharacteristicProperties object, which you can get to using characteristic.properties

```
//Check if the Characteristic is writable
if ((characteristic.properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite) ||
    (characteristic.properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse))
{
    //Do your Write here
}
```

Below is a simple method that takes a CBCharacteristicProperties object and logs the properties. . .helps with debugging.

```
-(void)logCharacteristicProperties:(CBCharacteristicProperties)properties {

    if (properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyBroadcast) {
        NSLog(@"CBCharacteristicPropertyBroadcast");
    }
    if (properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyRead) {
        NSLog(@"CBCharacteristicPropertyRead");
    }
    if (properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse) {
        NSLog(@"CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse");
    }
    if (properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite) {
        NSLog(@"CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite");
    }
    if (properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify) {
        NSLog(@"CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify");
    }
    if (properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate) {
        NSLog(@"CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate");
    }
    if (properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyAuthenticatedSignedWrites) {
        NSLog(@"CBCharacteristicPropertyAuthenticatedSignedWrites");
    }
    if (properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyExtendedProperties) {
        NSLog(@"CBCharacteristicPropertyExtendedProperties");
    }
    if (properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyNotifyEncryptionRequired) {
        NSLog(@"CBCharacteristicPropertyNotifyEncryptionRequired");
    }
    if (properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicateEncryptionRequired) {
        NSLog(@"CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicateEncryptionRequired");
    }
}
```

Also, you should be checking for Error to see if CoreBluetooth is throwing an error.

```
//CBPeripheral Delegate
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"<error> didWriteValueForCharacteristic %@",[error description]);
        //
        // Add Error handling for failed Writes
        //
    }

    //Add Handling for successful writes

}
```

Comment: I actually had to right some other CBCharacteristic before i could get CBCharacteristic in readable form.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 version

```
if((characteristic.properties.contains(CBCharacteristicProperties.write)) || (characteristic.properties.contains(CBCharacteristicProperties.writeWithoutResponse)))
{
     //Do your Write here
}
```